# What's the difference between downcasting and creating child object in java?

Tags: java

I write this one:

```
parent obj1=new Child();
Child obj2 =(Child)obj1; //downcasting
```

like this one:

```
Child obj2 = new Child(); //creating child object
```

Comment: The difference is meaningful if, in the first example, you'll use `obj1` for something else after the second assignment, for example.

Comment: Why would you ever use the 1st one in this exact instance?

Comment: Effectively, there is no difference, except that in the first you also have a variable `obj1` referencing the same object as `obj2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There difference is that in one case you have two references to one object.  In the other, you have two references pointing to two different objects.  Consider how it works with the following:

```
parent.kill();
if (child.isDead()) {
  System.out.println("He's dead");
} else {
  System.out.println("He lives!");
}
```

If the references point to the same object then we will print out "He's dead".  If they are pointing to two different objects then we will print out "He lives!".